# Kotlin Android, получить переменную из Strings в классе SQLite

Tags: android, kotlin

Как можно получить переменную из файла Strings в класса базы данных ?
Использую следующие методы, но безрезультативно, в активити все хорошо

```
var s = getString(R.string.peremOne)
```

Через

```
getResourses.getString()
```

тоже не работает
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Где всё хорошо? Где не можешь получить строку? Что за класс базы данных?

Comment: В обычном Activity, есть класс реализации SQLite, пытаюсь в его OnCreate получить строку из файла, в результате ничего

Comment: А причём здесь SQLite, если строки хранятся в простом txt файле values - strings?
Пишешь там строчку <string name="widget1">Строка 1</string> и работаешь с ней, как ты написал выше

Comment: Так в файле все задано, нужен доступ к ресурсу в классе, саму строку из txt не выходит получить

Comment: Но вы говорите в activity всё хорошо. Куда тогда не получается выводить?

Comment: В OnCreate базы данных, чтобы при установке приложения бд уже была с наполнением

Comment: Не понимаю, какая база данных и зачем она вам. Из базы данных совсме по другому значения получают. А то что вы написали в впоросе - из ресурсов

Comment: Для доступа к ресурсам нужен контекст. Активити является наследником контекста, поэтому получается достать строку.